# How do I load files in different subdirectories in a library into Datasheet View?

Tags: 2007, datasheet

I know how to load a list of files in a subdirectory into a Datasheet View, but how do I load files in different subdirectories in the same library into the same Datasheet View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to have some sort of view created that displays the items you want to see.  Set the folder scope to be show all items without folders when you create it.  You can then flip that over to datasheet view and do what you need to do.